# Set heap memory size from javascript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, heap-memory

I'm coding a script in node.js that rapidly goes out of memory when launched.

To resolve this problem i must augment the memory to >>5GB.I know for augment memory limit by command line is necessary to launch the script in this way: node max-old-space-size= script.js, that works perfectly.

My question is, how to set max-old-space-size from code? It's possible to set a variable from code, so who runs the script can omit max-old-space-size= in the command line?

What i want to obtain is that an user who download my script launch it and without setting anything the script works with the memory size i've set from code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: No, it is not possible to dynamically resize the heap at runtime, but there is nothing stopping you from forking a separate process with a larger heap.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you want is to respawn node from your script. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it should work.

```
# cat test.js
var cp = require('child_process');

function main() {
        console.log('This is the main script');
}

function spawn() {
        console.log('spawning the script with the correct node arguments');
        var c = cp.spawn('/opt/local/bin/node', ['--max-old-space-size=5120', __filename], {
                'stdio': 'inherit',
                'env': {
                        'RUN_MAIN_SCRIPT': 'TRUE'
                }
        });

        c.on('error', function (e) {
                console.log('Error');
                console.log(e.toString());
        });
}

process.env['RUN_MAIN_SCRIPT'] ? main() : spawn();
# node test.js
spawning the script with the correct node arguments
This is the main script
#
```